# change value in numpy array based on presence in another array

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

I want to change each value of an array (1D) based on whether this value is present in another array (1D) regardless of position.

I tried to come along with numpy.where() but couldn't find any working solution yet.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.array([5,6,7])

a = np.where(a in b, 0, -1)
```

evaluates to:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

what I want to get:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 -1 -1 -1 8 9]
```

**Edit**: Thanks a lot for your comments and sorry for not stating the question correctly. I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: Show us what you tried and what you obtained.

Comment: sample input and expected output please ? Your question is not clear enough

Comment: sorry for that, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a in b` here will always be False, but you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to remove by value:

```
>>> np.in1d(a,b)
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[np.in1d(a,b)] = 0
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9])
```

Or `where`, if you prefer:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> np.where(np.in1d(a,b), 999, a)
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4, 999, 999, 999,   8,   9])
```

Comment: thank you. this is what I was looking for. And I apologize for having my question not beeing more precise in terms of the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can index one array by another:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = np.array([5,6,7])

a[b] = 0    # [0 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 8 9]
```

Comment: yes, thank you. Is it also possible to inverse this? in the fashion of a[not b] = 0